# carrying a plastic toy sword in public in Austin, TX

Tags: texas, weapons

I plan to to a pub crawl with a couple of friends in Austin, TX and we will dress as fantasy characters in order to make things funnier. I plan to carry this ["sword"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SJPBRQE)  during that night.

I am not an US citizen so I'm not very confident with the law here. Am I allowed to do that? Is carrying a fake weapon a felony (even if it's clearly a toy)?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: You might "peace-bond" it by wrapping and knotting a rope/braid around it, thus binding it into the scabbard. That makes it more obvious that you don't plan to draw or use it.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 1, 2017 a new law is in effect in Texas allowing adults to openly carry knives with blades longer than 5.5 inches, including swords, spears, daggers, sabers, bowie knives and machetes.

So I would think that if you can legally carry the real thing around, that a toy or facsimile would be legal as well.

But in downtown Austin, you still might be questioned by police, but I doubt it if it's looks like a toy.

If you are carrying the real thing, you cannot carry them in certain places like bars, schools, prisons, hospitals, amusement parks, churches and sporting events.